# My legacy PSTricks code is not compilable anymore

Tags: beamer, luatex, pstricks, preview, ghostscript

The following code worked several years ago but it does not now. I lost my conscious and I might be in a generation gap. I attempted to compile with either `lualatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` sequence but it ends with errors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=1cm\relax

\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\RightPart
{
    \only<+->{\psline(0.5,2.7)(!6.5 3.5 82 eP2C)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(!6.5 3.5 73 eP2C)}
    \only<+->{\psellipticarcn(6.5,3.5){(!6.5 3.5 73 eP2C)}{(!6.5 3.5 73 neg eP2C)}}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(!6.5 3.5 -90 eP2C)}
}

\def\LeftPart
{
        \only<+->{\psbezier(1,-1)(1.5,-1)(2.2,-1.8)}  
        \only<+->{\psbezier(4,0)(4,-2)(!6.5 3.5 73 neg eP2C)}    
        \only<+->{\psellipticarc(6.5,3.5){(!6.5 3.5 73 neg eP2C)}}{(!6.5 3.5 73 eP2C)} 
        \only<+->{\psbezier(3.0,2.2)(3.0,1.0)(2.0,1.0)}
        \only<+->{\psbezier(1.3,1.0)(1.2,1.3)(!6.5 3.5 82 eP2C)}
    \only<+->{\psline(0.5,2.7)}
        \only<+->{\closepath}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7,-4)(7,4)
\pstVerb{/eP2C {PtoCab} def}%
%\psclip{%
\pscustom[dimen=m,linewidth=4\pslinewidth]
{
    \only<+->{\RightPart}
  \code{-1 1 scale}
  \LeftPart
    \only<+->{\fill[fillcolor=yellow,fillstyle=solid]}
}%}
\only<+->{\rput(0,0){\parbox{12cm}{\centering \bf\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont Entity Framework Core  \\ Happy Coding}}}
%\only<+->{\rput(-2.5,-.75){\includegraphics[scale=2.2]{parents}}}%
%\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- The errors when compiled with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`:
  [image: List item]
- The errors when compiled with `lualatex`:
  [image]

Note: For the sake of my convenience, the errors are intentionally sent as images.

Comment: +1: It may be useful to also post the error message.

Comment: I only had a few warnings  (overfullhbox), compiling with `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes. It is compilable with xelatex.

Comment: the problem is preview. It has not been adapted to the new shipout code of LaTeX and now choke over code in the shipout hooks.  If I remove preview it compiles in texlive 2022 both with lualatex and with latex-dvips-ps2pdf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

preview has not been adapted to the current LaTeX and chokes over some hooks. You can try to empty the hooks. For lualatex you should also load the pro-file in the picture:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=1cm\relax

\RemoveFromHook{shipout/firstpage}[hyperref]
\RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[hyperref]
\RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[beamerbasenavigation]

\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\RightPart
{
    \only<+->{\psline(0.5,2.7)(!6.5 3.5 82 eP2C)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(!6.5 3.5 73 eP2C)}
    \only<+->{\psellipticarcn(6.5,3.5){(!6.5 3.5 73 eP2C)}{(!6.5 3.5 73 neg eP2C)}}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(!6.5 3.5 -90 eP2C)}
}

\def\LeftPart
{
        \only<+->{\psbezier(1,-1)(1.5,-1)(2.2,-1.8)}
        \only<+->{\psbezier(4,0)(4,-2)(!6.5 3.5 73 neg eP2C)}
        \only<+->{\psellipticarc(6.5,3.5){(!6.5 3.5 73 neg eP2C)}}{(!6.5 3.5 73 eP2C)}
        \only<+->{\psbezier(3.0,2.2)(3.0,1.0)(2.0,1.0)}
        \only<+->{\psbezier(1.3,1.0)(1.2,1.3)(!6.5 3.5 82 eP2C)}
    \only<+->{\psline(0.5,2.7)}
        \only<+->{\closepath}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7,-4)(7,4)
\pstheader{pstricks.pro} % for luatex
\pstVerb{/eP2C {PtoCab} def}%
%\psclip{%
\pscustom[dimen=m,linewidth=4\pslinewidth]
{
    \only<+->{\RightPart}
  \code{-1 1 scale}
  \LeftPart
    \only<+->{\fill[fillcolor=yellow,fillstyle=solid]}
}%}
\only<+->{\rput(0,0){\parbox{12cm}{\centering \bf\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont Entity Framework Core  \\ Happy Coding}}}
%\only<+->{\rput(-2.5,-.75){\includegraphics[scale=2.2]{parents}}}%
%\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```